# Set CustomView delegate before init

Tags: swift, delegates, custom-view

Although I could create a `func setImages ()` in my CustomView class and call this after initializing `myCustomView`, I would like to understand if there's a cleaner way to set a view's delegate so that it is accessible when being initialized.

My main ViewController contains

```
class Main: UIViewController, CustomViewDelegate {

    var imagesArray:[UIImage] = [Image1,Image2,Image3,Image4,Image5]

    var myCustomView = CustomView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myCustomView.delegate = self
        myCustomView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        //this causes init of CustomView, but delegate is now nil and button images don't load
    }
}
```

My CustomView file contains

```
var buttonsArray = [Button1,Button2,Button3,Button4,Button5]

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame : frame)       

    for n in 0..< buttonsArray.count {
        buttonsArray[n].setImage(delegate?.imagesArray[n], for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not set the delegate _after_ you initialise your custom view?

Comment: @Sweeper i can but if delegate is set after, I can't access delegate in my CustomView init()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new initializer which takes a **frame** and a **delegate** type and set the delegate before you set images to buttons

```
 init(frame: CGRect,sender: CustomViewDelegate) {
    super.init(frame : frame)

    self.delegate = sender

    for n in 0..< buttonsArray.count {
       buttonsArray[n].setImage(delegate?.imagesArray[n], for: .normal)
    }
}
```

For that, you have to confirm your viewController for the delegate(obviously).Call your customView like this in viewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CustomViewDelegate {

    var myCustomView: CustomView!        

    override func viewDidLoad() {

       myCustomView = CustomView(frame: self.view.bounds, sender: self)
    }
}
```

hope it helps!

Comment: this is sort of solution i seek but... `override init(frame: CGRect, sender: CustomViewDelegate) {
        super.init(frame : frame, sender: sender)` causes errors

Comment: @Dustin There's no need of `override` as we are creating our custom initializer.

Comment: UIView only has `init(frame: CGRect)` & `init?(coder: NSCoder)`

Comment: @Dustin This is a custom initializer which we are creating, but we are calling `super.init(frame: frame)` to use the designated initializer of UIView.

Comment: @Dustin And since our ViewController satisfies the requirement of `CustomViewDelegate` You can set it in the initializer.

Comment: aha, okay but this causes errors on Main. my declaration of `var myCustomView = CustomView()`.. i tried to change this to `var myCustomView: CustomView` but this errors "class 'Main' has no initializers"

Comment: @Dustin which class is main, can you try `var myCustomView: CustomView!` or `var myCustomView: CustomView?`

Comment: @Dustin Edited the answer!